# How to Identify unusable assets in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, dataextensions, ssjs, content-builder

Is there any way by which we can identify unusable assets(email , content , DE, filter,automation,journey) in marketing cloud BU using SSJS or query ? Any other way to get this data ?
We need to export this detail for the client so that they can review and get it deleted.

Comment: What makes an asset unusable?

Comment: DE - whose records have not been modified since last 6 month. Email not being sent since last 6 month or part of any journey.